# How can I detect and warn the user when Javascript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, html

Websites can use the `<noscript>` tag to degrade gracefully (or warn the user) when their browser does not support or execute Javascript. However, some add-ons (e.g., NoScript, uMatrix) allow users to disable *third-party* Javascript, i.e., Javascript from the same website will run but Javascript served from other domains will not. This is a sensible thing to do for privacy and security concerns. However, it needs to be detected and handled for websites that crucially depend on third-party Javascript (e.g., Javascript libraries retrieved from a third-party CDN).

**How can I detect and warn users when their browser is blocking third-party Javascript?** Obviously I could do this by putting specific Javascript on another domain that I control, and testing whether it runs or not with Javascript on the main domain. However, this is cumbersome (need to manage another domain, etc.). Is there a simpler and cleaner solution?

Comment: Test connections to publicly available CDNs? Like jquery on cloudflare...

Comment: I'm fairly sure that if a user is selectively blocking JS they should be aware of the problems this might cause and should be able to detect and correct it by themselves.

Comment: Is the question "detect when an extension is utilizing `blockingWebRequest` or "detect if an extension is preventing js from executing"?

Comment: @Daniel_L: I'm interested about an extension preventing JS from being executed, no matter the mechanism.

Comment: @vlaz: I'm blocking 3rd-party JS myself, and when an unfamiliar site breaks in a non-obvious way, I don't always remember immediately that it may be because of broken JS. The reason why I am asking this question is because I'm wondering how I should design websites that don't break for users like myself.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, don't judge, can't you just do something like this

In case of jquery

```
if (typeof(jQuery) !== undefined)
{
//do something
}
```

So if the lib is not there just make a fallback

Comment: Again, this only works if they want to check if jQuery was loaded from a 3rd party. It doesn't handle the general case of seeing if 3rd party code can be loaded.

Comment: Can't manually list through all scripts you are trying to get? using same method

Comment: @Raimonds and check for what exactly? If you are loading `lodash.js` you will expect `_` to be there, if you are loading `underscore.js` you'd be expecting...`_` again. You have to write custom logic for each library you use _and_ keep that custom logic up to date, in case you update the library or something. It doesn't sound like a _generic_ solution.

Comment: I have not used lodash or underscore but I know that you ain't expecting $ in case of jQuery (obviously you can) but there for there is that jQuery variable not to mess $ with other libraries

Comment: ...not really. `jQuery` _is_ the jQuery library - `$` is a shorthand alias to that. If you have other libraries that also export `$` (e.g., Prototype), then you have to use `jQuery.noConflict()` which will prevent jQuery from grabbing the global `$` variable. At any rate, that is tangential - it still doesn't help with how to _generically_ solve this problem.